# C - compile with missing header files

Tags: c, header-files

I have the following simple C program:

```
void main()
{

    char *var = getenv("MYENV");

    if(var)
         printf("%x\n", (unsigned int)var);

}
```

The functions `getenv` and `printf` required header files `stdlib.h` and `stdio.h`. Even without including these header files, I can compile and run the program (it does show some warnings during compilation).

Warnings printed:

- initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
- incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf' [enabled by default]

I want to ask how can a C program run without errors without including necessary header files ? What is the role of header file then ?

Comment: Read the warnings you get.  Your code is working by sheer coincidence

Comment: A program may or may not run correctly when built with missing headers... it just depends on what information the compiler is missing. In your specific case, the information the compiler should have but doesn't is not enough to break execution due to the compiler assuming some defaults. Any reasonably real program will not be so fortunate (but in those cases, the compilation will probably fail rather than just emit warnings).

Comment: These functions are defined in libc.so

The dynamic linker will resolve the symbol in libc since you have not included it libc is default in gcc for every program. You can explicitly tell the linker to not link stdlib with "-nostdlib"

Comment: C is full of "default" and "implicit", so a program may compile and even work without the header files.

Comment: Under C90 rules, calls with no visible function declaration are legal. Under C99 rules, they're a *constraint violation*, requiring a diagnostic (which may be a non-fatal warning). Also, `void main()` should be `int main(void)`; if your book, tutorial, or instructor that tells you to use `void main()`, find a better one.

Comment: @ammoQ: It's not as full of "default" and "implicit" as it used to be. Many compilers, unfortunately, don't enforce modern C rules by default.

Comment: The currently accepted answer to the [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847949/how-could-my-code-compile-correctly-without-necessary-headers) is incomplete. I've posted a new answer.